# Bootstrap tooltips on a stacked progress bar

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to show Bootstrap tooltips on each element of a [stacked progress bar](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#progress-stacked). It seems possible to show one for the entire bar, but adding the code to the individual stacked bars does not work. Here's my code:

```
<div class="progress">
    <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-success" style="width: 35%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip on left">
         Used
     </div>
     <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-info" style="width: 10%" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Tooltip on left">
         Reserved
     </div>
</div>
```

If I add the tooltip code to `.progress` there is no issue, but tooltips on `.progress-bar` do not show. Is there something about the stacked bars that means it can't work?

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You probably forgot to init them, just add this to your JS:

```
 $('[data-toggle="tooltip"]').tooltip();
```

Or eventually, the tooltip itself could get stacked behind other DOM elements, so be sure to add `data-container="body"` to your inline data-* attributes

Working fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/w9qf9wo8/1/)

Comment: Hmm nope the init is there (sorry should have included that code), and it works on any other element on the page - just not the stacked bars. But clearly your fiddle works. Maybe I have some rogue CSS or JS affecting something? Hmm. I will keep searching. At least you've shown it is possible, thank you.

Comment: Thanks @Yuri, that `data-container` solved it! I will mark this as answer.